# Declaring multiple strings from code

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have something like:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\filter.xml");
string filter1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f1").InnerText;
string filter2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f2").InnerText;
string filter3 = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f3").InnerText;
string filter4 = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f4").InnerText;
string filter5 = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f5").InnerText;
string filter6 = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f6").InnerText;
```

And so on...My question is how could I generate these strings in a loop?something like.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\filter.xml");
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    string filter + i = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f" + i).InnerText;;        
}
```

Comment: Use an array, hashmap, list, dictionary, ...

Comment: It would help to know how `filter`s 1-6 are used *after* they've been populated.

Comment: where will you use filter strings?

Comment: I will not use them in the same for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a collection, like `List<string>`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\filter.xml");
var myList = new List<strinig>;

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    myList.Add(doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f" + i).InnerText);     
}
```

Then you can use the list by referencing a string's index:

```
myValue = myList[3];
```

Answer (score 4):

Fill a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> filterList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    filterList.Add(doc.SelectSingleNode("filter/f" + i).InnerText);
}
```

Now you can access them via index, f.e. filter 5:

```
string filter5 = filterList[4]; // zero based
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Collection to store String and this is how you can add string to collection from the XML.

```
        doc.Load(@"D:\filter.xml");
        List<string> filter = new List<string>();
        foreach (XmlNode item in doc.SelectSingleNode("filter").ChildNodes)
        {
            filter.Add(item.InnerText.ToString());
        }
```

Hope this helps.